# Nesting tikz pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, nesting

I do prepare some standalone tikz pictures, which later I want to combine in a 'subfigure' style. Is it possible to put tikz pictures, drawn in absolute coordinates, into nodes, and combine them the usual way; or is there a better idea?

Comment: Nesting TikZ pictures is not good idea. See, if another approach can solve your problem. For example smal pictures (`pi`) or  to node fit (by using `fit` TikZ library) around.

Comment: Or compile them standalone, then include them.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Presently I compile them standalone and display them as a 'subfigure'. Why I do not really like it, that I would like to put one 'subfigure' shared between two other 'subfigures'.